# So where exactly do I configure user snippets in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

[The documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets) has this to say:

> You can easily define your own snippets without any extension. To create or edit your own snippets, select **User Snippets** under **File** > **Preferences** (**Code** > **Preferences** on macOS), and then select the language (by [language identifier](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/identifiers)) for which the snippets should appear [...]

So I went to preferences and tried to search the setting mentioned above:

[image: It says "No Settings Found". Yeah weird capitalization, isn't it]

So, where do I configure my snippets? Am I reading outdated documentation somehow? Or viewing the wrong settings?

Comment: User Snippets means Snippets under User.  There are Global VS code settings under User and project specific settings under Workspace.  Try searching for just snippets, and make sure the User Tab is selected.

Comment: there is a very nice doc page describing snippets

Comment: Go to the Gear icon in the lower left, click it and choose `Configure User Snippets`.  It is a command, not a setting.  So you can also find it in the Command Palette.